# Questions about interrupt handler

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, interrupt

I'm currently developing a simple ARM firmware.
Among them, I'm making a part related to interrupts.
I connected the IRQ exception vector in the exception vector table with the interrupt handler in the interrupt controller as follows:

```
__attribute__ ((interrupt ("IRQ"))) void Irq_Handler(void) 
{
   interrupt_handler();
}
```

And it converted to ARM assembly code:

```
sub    lr, lr, #4
push   {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, fp, ip, lr}
add    fp, sp, #28
bl     0 <interrupt_hanlder>
sub    sp, fp, #28
ldm    sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, fp, ip, pc}^
```

I have several questions for this assembly code:

1. Why it pushes registers "r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, fp, ip, lr" to the stack?
2. It pushes 8 registers to the stack. But why it subtracts not 32(4*8) but 28(4*7)?
3. I don't know the meaning of '^' at the end of 6th line.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. because those registers are call-clobbered, but this is an interrupt handler that has to preserve (almost?) all registers.  2. notice that it's setting up a frame pointer (I assume this is without optimization), not reserving more stack space.  I think It's normal it points to one of the saved registers.  3. IDK.

Comment: Have you checked out the [LDM docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/Cihcadda.html)?  It talks about `^`

Answer (score 2):

> Why it pushes registers "r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, fp, ip, lr" to the stack?

This is done because these registers may be modified by the function `interrupt_handler()`. An interrupt interrupts a running program anywhere. For example here:

```
ldm r0, {r2, r3}
                 <=== The interrupt interrupts the program here
add r1, r2, r3
```

If the interrupt modified some registers (in the example: `r2` or `r3`), the program which has been interrupted would not be running correctly anymore.

For this reason the interrupt must restore all registers to their original values.

The function `interrupt_handler()` will not modify registers `r5`, `r6`, ..., so the interrupt handler does not need to restore these registers.

> It pushes 8 registers to the stack. But why it subtracts not 32(4*8) but 28(4*7)?

For some reason the `fp` register shall contain the value `sp+28`. Maybe it shall point to the stored value of the `lr` register.

The instruction `sub sp, fp, #28` will restore the value of `sp` assuming that the value of `fp` did not change since the instruction `add fp, sp, #28`.

In your case, `sp` did not change, so the instruction is redundant.

> I don't know the meaning of `^` at the end of 6th line.

The `^` is used for the `ldm` and `stm` instructions and has two different effects.

One of the two effects is that loading the `pc` register will also load the `psr` register.

To return from an interrupt, you must restore the `psr` register.

Note that in early ARM CPUs, the register `r15` contained both the `pc` register (which was only 24 bits wide) and the `psr` register (which was 8 bits wide). A `ldm` without `^` would keep the 8 `psr` bits of the register `r15` unchanged while using `^` would load all 32 bits from memory.

In current ARM CPUs this is no longer the case. However, using the `^` still restores the value of the `psr` register when loading the `pc` using `ldm`.

Comment: Thanks for your teaching. Actually I missed one question. At first line, 8 registers are pushed into the stack. Then as I thought, sp(or fp) should increases 32byte (4byte * 8 registers). But it increases only 28byte. Is there any reason??

Comment: @Woong Not neccessarily. The `stm` and `ldm` instructions will actually change the `sp` register by 32 bytes. However, the register `fp` may have any value. The compiler decides to set `fp` to `sp+28` for some reason. Some compilers will modify the `sp` register inside a function. However, the `fp` register is normally not modified. For this reason the compiler uses the `fp` register (which is `sp+28`) to ensure that `sp` has the correct value.